# Definition of " Wan't "

Tags: contractions, definition

I was having fun in another stackexchange when I found this sentence :

> I **wan't** a plausible explanation why farmers can't out-compete the hunter gatherers.

Context is here : https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/58436/is-it-possible-to-have-a-planet-unsuitable-for-agriculture

But even with the context, I can't figured out what **wan't** means. Did it means *want* or *want not* or both ? Wikitionary and yahoo were no help.

Comment: I am not native, feel free to edit my post to correct my grammar.

Comment: It's just a typo. He should have written *I **want** a plausible explanation* - same as the first sentence of his question, starting *I **want** to have a planet similar to earth...*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo

Comment: It is a misspelling  of the term "want" https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/wan%27t

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it appears to be more than a simple  mispelling: ***Misspelt by confusion with words formed with the enclitic n't.*** https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/wan%27t

Comment: I thought it may be a typo, but as a non native, I see n't as a pattern. It has nothing to do ?

Comment: @Carlos2W - yes, it has to do with the n't pattern, see the link above.

Comment: @Absolute Beginner: Maybe in a different context, where we have reason to suspect the writer is woefully illiterate. But as I pointed out, in this specific case it's obvious the writer *can* spell ***want*** correctly, since he did so successfully in the second word of his question. And I have to add that even though I often feel that I'm surrounded by illiterates, I personally don't recall *ever* seeing such a daft mistake before this ELL question.

Comment: ...note that there *are* contexts where ***wan't*** is a valid "eye dialect" representation of slightly sub-standard enunciation, as in *It wan't me!* for *It wasn't me! = It was not me!* (though possibly that's influenced by dialectal *It **weren't** me!*).

Comment: Wan't : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wan%27t&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwan%27t%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner looks like your ngram doesn't work, but I found this : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wan%27t&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwan%27t%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwan%27t%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWan%27t%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Carlos2W: Your NGram doesn't work either - probably because as implied by my earlier comment, this is a ***very rare*** type of orthographic error, so NGram fails for lack of sufficient results. But [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+wan%27t+to%22) includes at least *some* hits (GB doesn't actually index apostrophes, so it just matches any character including a space). But in general, people who are illiterate enough to make this kind of mistake aren't likely to use apostrophes in the first place (unless they're trainee ***greengrocer's**!* :)

Comment: @Carlos2W - it should work, just click on "search lots of books" bottom.

Comment: This may be an example of the _I don't understand the apostrophe in English so I'll just insert them here and there_ syndrome. A perfect example was seen in a Greek diner in New York years ago on a sign inviting diners to eat there on an approaching holiday: **"Xmas is coming! Dine here with San'ta Clau's!"**